# The old style network activity icon with animation - how to get it back?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

I found it quite useful to have network activity flashing in my sys tray, as I have no LED on my laptop that does a similar function. Whats the optimal way of getting the original functionality back?

Answer (score 3):

There are [3rd party tools](http://www.dalesplace.net/download/lanlight.php) which do what you want.

But alternatively you could install (another 3rd party tool) [Network Lights](http://www.itsamples.com/software/nl.html):

> Network Lights is a Windows program,
>   which blinks keyboard LEDs (Light
>   Emitting Diode) indicating outgoing
>   and incoming network packets on
>   network interface.
>   Network Lights lets
>   you monitor network activity
>   (upload/download) from your keyboard
>   ScrollLock and NumLock indicators.
>   Each LED will flicker when network
>   traffic is detected.

Comment: I tried network lights, problem is that the only leds (plus batt/hdd) I have on my laptop are num/caps locks. Network lights lights toggles these and screws with my keyboard when I'm typing.