# Windows 7 - network activity lights

Tags: windows-7, notifications

I'm looking for a network activity notification indicator for Windows-7 (Windows XP had, remember?).

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/89976/visual-indication-of-network-activity) SU question and, although it provides a 3rd party solution, it does not provide a solution for the notifications, but through hardware LEDs.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/19809/the-old-style-network-activity-icon-with-animation-how-to-get-it-back-or-a-sim) is VERY similar without the requirement of the solution to be a notification solution. In the answer there is a broken link and the above mentioned Network Lights.

Anyway to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn on the activity animation, or use another product by the same creators of Network Lights, [**Network Activity Indicator**](http://www.itsamples.com/network-activity-indicator.html). It will indicate incoming as well as outgoing traffic, and you can even change the blink duration:

[image]

> Network Activity Indicator displays
>   the old 'two monitors' icon in Windows
>   7 that flashed blue to show network
>   activity on the System Tray.
>
> Unlike the original Windows XP utility
>   (that has individual indicators for
>   each interface), this program
>   indicates outgoing and incoming
>   network packets on all available
>   interfaces.

Network Activity Indicator is freeware.

Comment: Thanks! Tested it and it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slick one I just found.  Installed it and it works like a charm in Windows 7.

> http://www.paulmather.net/lanlight.asp

[image]

Not only lights in the task bar, but also a popup with traffic graphs, etc.

Comment: +1 that's actually the program from aforementioned 'broken link' :)

Comment: I kind of figured it was, but didn't want to say it was when I didn't know. It's nice for sure, but personally I've got other, crazy-wasteful gadgets in Win 7 telling me this stuff already instead. :D Thanks for the pic add-on edit.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may be missing something here. Do you just mean the system tray network activity?

[image: activity light screenshot]

Edit: ah, Vista screenshot. Why was this removed in Windows 7...

Comment: You missed the Windows 7 part.

Comment: No I... Oh. I may have not noticed what operating system I was running.

Comment: (In my defense, a windows 7 VM and a windows vista VM don't look that different :( )